# How to display the Navigation item title in IOS 7?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7, uinavigationbar

I'm using this code.suggest me.

```
UINavigationItem *navigationItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
    self.navigationItem.title=@"Mliestones";
```

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"The title";
```